# Recursive PATH variable?

Tags: linux, shell, recursion, path

This is more of a curiosity question, but I feel it's worth asking.

Frequently when downloading software on Linux, I'm used to using `sudo apt-get install [package]` or whatever package manager is available, but for some projects like sbt, they don't have a repository (so I can't just type `sudo apt-get install sbt` and use it out of the box). I have to download the binaries and add them to PATH.

What I like to do is create a directory specific to programs like sbt, specifically `~/Programs`. I move the unpacked directory into it, and add it to PATH. However, I'm always a little wary about moving the binary out of the directory it came in, so I don't want to remove it.

Is there such a thing as a recursive PATH variable, so that not only `~/Programs` is added but also `~/Programs/sbt`, `~/Programs/other_program`, etc.? And if not, is it a good idea to make it recursive? I've tinkered with the Linux kernel before as part of a university class, I wonder if it's worth experimenting with.

Comment: It might be worth looking into GNU Stow and similar tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to *~/.bashrc* or *~/.bash_profile*:

```
for each in ~/Programs/*
do
  PATH+=:"$each"
done
```